# How to do an Ajax GET request to get data from rails and pass it to javascript(google maps)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model Locations with two columns latitude and longitude. I want to find a way where I can get the list of locations and pass them to google maps using Ajax and javascript. So far my code is as follows:

map.js:

```
function initialize() 
{   
    var map;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71);
    var options = {
    zoom: 5, 
    center: latlng, 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    noClear: true,
    navigationControl: true,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    }
    };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng, 
    map: map, 
    title: 'Click me', 
    });
}
```

locations_controller.rb

```
def show
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @location }
    end
  end
```

Page displaying the map:

```
<div id="map" onload="initialize();">
</div>
```

SO now I want to find a way to make an AJAX request from map.js so I can get the locations from the Location model and pass it to the marker object so that when a map is loading all the locations pre-existing in the database are passed to marker and those markers appear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh I was able to find my way to get the list of locations. The controller and view are left untouched.

I added the following ajax in map.js which did the work for me.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/locations",
        success: function(data){}
    });
```

Now data can be passed to the marker object in google maps.